# Use of remove() method in ArrayAdapter<Integer>

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView of items. Each of the items contains a TimeTextView (it's just a simple class that displays time the way I want), another TextView and a Button to remove the item from the ListView. For that I extended the class ArrayAdapter and rewrote the method getView() like so :

```
public class TimeListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

private Context applicationContext = null;
private int layout = 0;

private class ViewHolder {
    public TimeTextView timeText;
    public TextView position;
    public ImageButton removeButton;
}

TimeListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Integer> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    applicationContext = context;
    layout = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Integer newTime = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) applicationContext.
            getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.timeText = (TimeTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_text);
        holder.position = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.position);
        holder.removeButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove_button);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.timeText.setTime(newTime);
    holder.position.setText((new Integer(position + 1)).toString() + ".");
    holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            remove(newTime);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Now my problem is, if you put two items with the same value, the call of the remove() method automatically removes the first one even if you clicked on the button of the second item. For example if you have the values (12, 16, 12) in your list and you click on the button to remove the third item, the first one gets removed.

The only solution I found so far was to make an IntegerWrapper class that simply contains an Integer as a public attribute. But I find it very inconvenient to use in the rest of my code.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following

- Register onItemClickListener in you Activity class this will give you a method onItemClick in that method do the following

  ```
          arrayAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(
          new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
             objects.remove(position);
          arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      });
  ```

This will remove the position you wanted.

Comment: Ok but I want this behavior only when I click on the button, not on the whole item... Though that helped me a lot. The solution is to put the TimeListAdapter class as an inner class of the activity. Instead of the code of the onClick method I've written, you just put the code of your onItemClick. Thanks :)